# Complex prefetch_related

Tags: django, django-orm

There is a request which returns a list of several Lists with their movies. I want to use prefetch to Lists to optimize db calls.

I have several models:

```py
    class List(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField()

    class ListMovie(models.Model):
        list = models.ForeignKey(List)
        movie = models.ForeignKey(Movie)

    class Movie(models.Model): 
         title = models.CharField()
         other_fields...
```

I have a  separate prefetch for Movie to get other fields.

Is there a way to concatenate prefetch list of List objects with their movies  and prefetch additional movie info?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, try like this:

```
List.objects.all().prefetch_related('listmovie__movie')
```

---

**From updated question**, as far as I know, you can't concatenate reverse relation objects with queryset. You can concatenate one object's field from all related objects using [**`subquery`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions). Like this:

```
from django.db.models import Subquery, OuterRef

newest = ListMovie.objects.filter(list=OuterRef('pk'))

List.objects.annotate(listmovie=Subquery(newest.values('pk')[0]))
```

Alternatively, you can use [**`values queryset`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#values) to show fields. For example:

```
 List.objects.values('listmovie').prefetch_related('listmovie__movie')
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I missed some additional details. I have updated my question.